# GNU Radio hangs when I call a getter function on a block

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, gnuradio

I'm running GNU Radio 3.7 on Linux, CentOS 7. (I know this is old; our customer seems allergic to change. For the time being, I’m stuck with it.)

I’m testing an OOT Python block, a source block created with `gr_modtool`. This block includes a queue (`queue.Queue`, Python 2.7) where it occasionally puts objects. My testing code gets the objects off the queue. The testing code gets 10 objects off the queue with blocking `get` calls, successfully, then it does some very simple tests. In the course of these tests, the test code calls one of the block’s getter functions, just

```
def amplitude(self):
    return self._amplitude
```

At this point, GNU Radio hangs. A print statement in the getter function prints `self._amplitude` correctly, but then a print statement in the test code, directly after the call to `amplitude`, never prints. Print statements in the block’s `work` function show the block’s thread entering `work` and leaving `work`, but `work` never executes again after the call to `amplitude`.

The flow graph I’m using in the test code is very simple:

```
    My_source_block -> throttle -> GR’s debug tag block
```

I don’t know how to debug this. If a block’s thread dies for some reason, does GNU Radio just quit silently? Perhaps the block raises an exception and GNU Radio swallows it and dies some time later. I don’t know how to find out. I can’t imagine why a call to `amplitude` from the test code would cause a problem, particularly when a print statement put in `amplitude` prints the correct value of `self._amplitude` successfully.

Another peculiarity: My block runs just fine in `gnuradio_companion`.

I’m out of ideas. Thoughts?